# Not getting latest data in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using Wire method to fetch data but its not getting latest data.When I change record in UI. And click on button showing old values only. Below are sample codes.
I am using this LWC in quick action.
[image]

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true) public static personAccountDataWrapper
      getPersonAccountTimeZone(Id optyId) {
    Opportunity opty =
        [ select Id, Name, AccountId, Account.Timezone__c, Account.Name,
          StageName from Opportunity where Id =:optyId ];

    personAccountDataWrapper pdw = new personAccountDataWrapper();
    pdw.personAccountName = opty.Account.Name;
    pdw.timezoneValue = opty.Account.Timezone__c;
    pdw.currentDt = system.now().adddays(1);
    if (opty.StageName.contains('Closed')) {
      pdw.isOptyClosed = true;
    } else {
      pdw.isOptyClosed = false;
    }
    system.debug('====pdw==' + pdw);
    return pdw;
  }

  public class personAccountDataWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled public String personAccountName {
      get;
      set;
    }
    @AuraEnabled public String timezoneValue {
      get;
      set;
    }
    @AuraEnabled public Boolean isOptyClosed {
      get;
      set;
    }
    @AuraEnabled public DateTime currentDt {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is because of `@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)` as we can't use wire without `cacheable = true` so Call Apex Methods Imperatively.

Comment: So is there any way to get latest data without going to Imperative?

Comment: what's the mechanism for changing `recordId`? A click of a button?

Comment: Nope, if you want to get latest data then go with Imperative apex call.

Comment: IMHO while there are ways to revoke the cache for wires, you simply shouldn't do this in 99.99% of cases; to do so is to "hack" the Salesforce data service infrastructure. Better to switch to imperative where you have full control of invocation and you can define your Apex as not cacheable.

Comment: With imperative method how to get data when LWC component is loading. How to call the apex method without any click of button in LWC.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected. As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

> We call the wire service reactive in part because it supports reactive variables, which are prefixed with $. If a reactive variable changes, the wire service provisions new data. **We say “provisions” instead of “requests” or “fetches” because if the data exists in the client cache, a network request may not be involved**

Emphasis is mine.

If you need to guarantee receipt of up-to-date data, switch to using [imperative Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative). Continuing to use a wire and then using `refreshApex` to clear the local cache is a hack in 99.99% of cases and shouldn't be done.

You'll find information about how to call Apex that expects parameters in that [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative) under the heading "Call an Apex Method with Parameters".

Comment: How to call imperative method with passing id